# $a+b,a+2b,a+3b,\ldots$

Tags: number-theory

> For any integer $k>0$, establish that the arithmetic progression
>   $$a+b,a+2b,a+3b,...$$
>   where $\gcd(a,b)=1$, contains $k$ consecutive terms that are composite.
>
> [Hint: Put $n=(a+b)(a+2b)···(a+kb)$ and consider the $k$ terms $a+(n+1)b,
> a+(n+2)b,...,a+(n+k)b$.]

So I tried to follow the hint and I substituted the suggested expression of $n$ to rewrite my progression as follows:

$$a+[(a+b)(a+2b)···(a+kb)+1]b\cdot [(a+b)(a+2b)···(a+kb)+2]b$$ $$\cdot [(a+b)(a+2b)···(a+kb)+3]b\cdots a+[(a+b)(a+2b)···(a+kb)+k]b$$

But this is a long and ugly expression. Is there a neater way?

Please help me. And please avoid using congruence relations. My class has not yet learned those at this point in the semester.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
  a+(n+r)b &= a+(a+b)(a+2b)\cdots(a+kb)b + rb \\
    &= (a+rb)+(a+b)(a+2b)\cdots(a+rb)\cdots(a+kb)b,
\end{align*}
which is divisible by $a+rb$, for $r = 1, 2, \dotsc, k$.

Answer (score 0):

Take that first expression, 
$$
a+[(a+b)(a+2b)···(a+kb)+1]b
$$
You'd like to show it's composite, i.e., you want to factor it. Well, go ahead and expand out a bit:
\begin{align}
a+[(a+b)(a+2b)···(a+kb)+1]b&= 
a+[b(a+b)(a+2b)···(a+kb)+b] \\
&= b(a+b)(a+2b)···(a+kb)+(a+b)
\end{align}
which is obviously divisible by $(a+b)$, hence is composite. Can you do something similar for the next term in the sequence?